# IIS Recycle Global.asax

Tags: iis, events, global-asax, recycle

Is it possible to catch an recycle event in the global.asax?

I know Application_End will be triggered but is there a way to know that it was triggered by a recycle of the application pool?

thx, Lieven Cardoen aka Johlero

Comment: App Recycle can be a pretty brutal affair depending on the state of your process - worst scenario is Win32::TerminateProcess being called. There is no way to trap such an outcome in your process.  What are you trying to achieve?  Flushing some state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, here is an idea how this could work.

Based on my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294113/iis-recycle-globalasax#294126) (attach to AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit) and [stephbu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12702/stephbu)'s comment:

> This will trap most structured process
>   teardowns e.g. - but I'm not sure that
>   it will trap all tear downs. e.g.
>   http://blogs.msdn.com/jmstall/archive/2006/11/26/process-exit-event.aspx
>   Process recycle will kill the process
>   if it seems to be hung - your handler
>   wouldn't get called.

I suggest following strategy:

In the (regular) ProcessExit handler (which we suppose will not be called on a application pool recycling), write some file to disk like "`app_domain_end_ok.tmp`".

Then in the Application_Start of your global.asax check for this file. If it doesn't exist it is a sign that the application was not terminated in a clean way (or that it is the first time ever it started). Don't forget to delete this file from disk after the check.

I didn't try that myself, but it could be worth a try.

Comment: I've not validated this but I suspect that process recycler has two strategies - 1) signal terminate process and wait while polling for process exit - it should trigger ProcessExit in normal conditions.  2) On timeout of wait kill PID.

Answer (score 7):

I found this article on **Scott Guthries's blog**:

[**Logging ASP.NET Application Shutdown Events**](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/14/433194.aspx)

> Someone on a listserv recently asked
>   whether there was a way to figure out
>   why and when ASP.NET restarts
>   application domains.  Specifically, he
>   was looking for the exact cause of
>   what was triggering them on his
>   application in a production shared
>   hosted environment (was it a
>   web.config file change, a global.asax
>   change, an app_code directory change,
>   a directory delete change,
>   max-num-compilations reached quota,
>   \bin directory change, etc).
>
> Thomas on my team has a cool
>   code-snippet that he wrote that uses
>   some nifty private reflection tricks
>   to capture and log this information. 
>   It is pretty easy to re-use and add
>   into any application, and can be used
>   to log the information anywhere you
>   want (the below code use the NT Event
>   Log to save it – but you could just as
>   easily send it to a database or via an
>   email to an admin).  The code works
>   with both ASP.NET V1.1 and ASP.NET
>   V2.0.
>
> Simply add the System.Reflection and
>   System.Diagnostics namespaces to your
>   Global.asax class/file, and then add
>   the Application_End event with this
>   code:

```
public void Application_End() {

    HttpRuntime runtime = 
       (HttpRuntime) typeof(System.Web.HttpRuntime).InvokeMember("_theRuntime",
          BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.GetField, 
          null, null, null);

    if (runtime == null)
        return;

    string shutDownMessage = 
       (string) runtime.GetType().InvokeMember("_shutDownMessage",
           BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetField,
           null, runtime, null);

    string shutDownStack = 
       (string) runtime.GetType().InvokeMember("_shutDownStack",
           BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetField,
           null, runtime, null);

    if (!EventLog.SourceExists(".NET Runtime")) {
        EventLog.CreateEventSource(".NET Runtime", "Application");
    }

    EventLog log = new EventLog();
    log.Source = ".NET Runtime";

    log.WriteEntry(String.Format(
          "\r\n\r\n_shutDownMessage={0}\r\n\r\n_shutDownStack={1}", 
          shutDownMessage, shutDownStack),
       EventLogEntryType.Error);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried this myself, but you could try to attach an event handler to the ProcessExit event of the AppDomain.

```
...
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler(OnExit);
...

void OnExit(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // do something
}
```

*I hope this helps!*

Comment: This will trap most structured process teardowns e.g. - but I'm not sure that it will trap all tear downs.

e.g. http://blogs.msdn.com/jmstall/archive/2006/11/26/process-exit-event.aspx

Process recycle will kill the process if it seems to be hung - your handler wouldn't get called.

Answer (score 0):

I was much more successful with attaching to DomainUnload event, it is triggered on AppPool recycle and stoppage of the AppPool itself.

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainUnload += this.CurrentDomainOnProcessExit;`