# logging application pool recycle

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5, application-pool

I am using ELMAH to log errors, and NLog as my logging framework.

Is it possible to capture application pool recycles from IIS 7.5, and log them using NLog?

Website is developed using .Net Framework 4.5, IIS 7.5 & C#.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294113/iis-recycle-global-asax/294126#294126
You can log into event log: http://blogs.iis.net/ganekar/archive/2008/12/12/iis-7-0-application-pool-recycles-log-a-event-in-windows-event-log.aspx