# Invoke a website hosted on IIS at a particular interval automatically

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, timer, application-pool

I am trying to Invoke a website hosted on IIS at a particular interval automatically.
**Steps that I followed**.
 1. I tried to invoke the website on app pool recycle period. But none of the events on Global file are invoked on app pool recycle.
 2. Application_End on Global file is invoked on app pool recycle only if web-site is active.
 3. Is there any way to invoke the global file events on app pool recycle ? 
 4. Is there any other way, so that,I can invoke the website at a particular interval automatically.
Please advice..

Comment: You want to invoke, periodically, your web site, but I can't understand from where? From a client application? From another side? From Javascript?

Comment: @ Roberto : It is just hosted on IIS. That website needs to be triggered automatically at intervals like windows scheduler.
We are not allowed to use windows scheduler.
Hope you understand me

Comment: I hope this article can help you understanding "pools" on IIS. After, I suggest you to use "Quartz.Net" library to schedule operations on your web site: http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/why-is-the-iis-default-app-pool-recycle-set-to-1740-minutes I hope this can help

Comment: let me go through this article. Your help is very important for me. I will update you again.

Comment: @Roberto : Thanks for the article. Actually I want to invoke some method on my hosted Web App while App pool recycle. But the Web App won't be active. The article says about when the Web App is active.

Comment: Well... I suppose this answer can help you understanding the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294113/iis-recycle-global-asax