# Detect when IIS recycles the application pool

Tags: c#, iis, websocket, application-pool

Is there any good way to detect when the IIS Application pool resets and creates a new worker process?

I need to detect this event to disconnect a web socket connection. This is keeping the process from shutting down even after the 90 second time limit has elapsed at which time IIS normally kills the process.

I have tried using the application_end() method to do this but when the worker process has a WS connection this method does not seem to be called until the connection is broken.

Comment: How about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294113/iis-recycle-global-asax)?

Comment: Other ways are monitoring the event log for the recorded w3svc event and monitoring the PID in PowerShell or C#